# Font editor for Windows

Tags: windows, font-utility, unicode

I'm looking for a font editor possibly with the following specs:

- ability to edit / import most common types of fonts (ttf, woff etc)
- export / import svg files as glyphs
- set basic glyph positioning with grid support (as in illustrator)
- full unicode support (including latest 6+) with named sections
- lightweight and with a native interface
- not a vectors editor, just a font editor

Any kind of software is welcome, including commercial software.

Answer (score 5):

There are two options I'm aware of that will work natively under Windows:

- [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) is the obvious suggestion. It helps that it is cross-platform. One screen-shot:

  [image: FontForge]
- [Softy](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204233227/http://users.breathe.com/l-emmett/) is a very old piece of software (shareware), but again, depending on the platform, it might continue to be useful. I used it quite a bit many years ago, and it was great for tweaking TTF fonts (**pre-Unicode** days). A [third-party review](http://www.muledog.com/magazine/Spring2000/softy.html) fills in details:

  [image: Softy]

  It runs under "Windows (3.1, 95, 98, NT)", but I'm quite certain I used it with XP as well. (And as I update a dead link in 2018, can confirm that it still works under Wine in Ubuntu 1.04 LTS!)

Comment: `although it was later tagged with windows, although how that was discerned, I can't see!` The title said "for Windows" since the very first day.

Answer (score 2):

Font Creator. It allows more than 2,000 composite glyphs as well as import images (GIF, PNG, BMP, etc.) and vector files (PDF, AI, EPS, etc).

Answer (score 0):

[Fontlab studio 5](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/) (shareware) is the best software for font editing. It has a trial version available. It has numerous useful tweak option for fonts and you can include Python scripts.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it may be removed. SPecifically go over the requirements identified in the question and confirm whether this matches them or not would be a significant improvement.

Comment: @ṧнʊß Ready made with a bit extra specific to the individual instance I'm responding to. I use the userscript version great Firefox/Chrome addon [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) - see also [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13278/autoreviewcomment-script-devel) and [GitHub source](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments).